# npm - how to show the latest version of a package

Tags: node.js, npm, versioning

How do I use npm to show the latest version of a module? I am expecting something like `npm --latest express` to print out `v3.0.0`.

Comment: check a package's semantic version [semver.npmjs.com](https://semver.npmjs.com)

Answer (score 638, accepted):

You can use:

```
npm view {pkg} version
```

(so `npm view express version` will return now `3.0.0rc3`).

Comment: `npm view`, `npm show`, `npm info`, and `npm v` all do the same thing.

Comment: this way involves loads poking around to find latest version, npm outdated seems to be the best way

Comment: How can you show latest stable version. i.e. not beta version

Comment: ah npm show {pkg} versions. version can be plural which will show all versions.

Comment: If only there was a way to check the versions of multiple packages like this in one bulk request to the registry. Is there?

Answer (score 317):

If you're looking for the current and the latest versions of all your installed packages, you can also use:

`npm outdated`

Comment: I've looked at the whole post at least 5 times when I need to get the latest version of packages and I had never seen this, but it seems easier than running a number of other commands to check if you have libraries out of date

Comment: to learn what the columns mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689865/npm-wanted-vs-latest

Comment: a nice video explains how `outdated` and `update` work from NPM https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-local-packages

Comment: THIS IS THE MOST USEFUL! I wish `npm update` would just run this too - so I can at least see the latest versions. When you only run these commands once a month or so it's hard to remember all the options.

Comment: Except never mind - no it isn't. It shows me a completely blank column for latest, where I know some things have newer major versions :-/

Comment: Given how many users have found this answer helpful. Would it make sense to append this answer to the selected one?

Comment: this *seems* to just show outdated packages in a project, how to show outdated globally installed packages?

Answer (score 102):

As of **October 2014**:

[image: npm view illustration]

For latest remote version:

```
npm view <module_name> version
```

Note, *version* is singular.

If you'd like to see all available (remote) versions, then do:

```
npm view <module_name> versions
```

Note, *versions* is plural. This will give you the full listing of versions to choose from.

To get the version you actually have locally you could use:

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep <module_name>
```

Note, even with package.json declaring your versions, the installed version might actually differ slightly - for instance if tilda was used in the version declaration

Should work across NPM versions 1.3.x, 1.4.x, 2.x and 3.x

Comment: How would you get the last entry in `npm view <module_name> versions`?

Comment: `npm view <module_name> versions` command is very useful. + we can install a specific version of a package using `npm install <module_name>@<version_number>`

Comment: The last command, it's such an ugly and a challenging thing to remember. I wonder why they have not come up with a shorthand for that? for the local version or same as the other two, but with a `-L` (lowercase optional)?

Answer (score 16):

You can see all the version of a module with `npm view`.
eg: To list all versions of bootstrap including beta.

```
npm view bootstrap versions
```

But if the version list is very big it will truncate. An `--json` option will print all version including beta versions as well.

```
npm view bootstrap versions --json
```

If you want to list only the stable versions not the beta then use singular `version`

```
npm view bootstrap@* versions
```

Or

```
npm view bootstrap@* versions --json
```

And, if you want to see only latest version then here you go.

```
npm view bootstrap version
```

Answer (score 11):

The `npm view <pkg> version` prints the last version by release date. That might very well be an hotfix release for a older stable branch at times.

The solution is to list all versions and fetch the last one by version number

```bash
$ npm view <pkg> versions --json | jq -r '.[-1]'
```

Or with awk instead of jq:

```bash
$ npm view <pkg> versions --json  | awk '/"$/{print gensub("[ \"]", "", "G")}'
```

Comment: I was in this exact case, and this answer was the most helpful to me! Thank you so much! Btw, you have a typo in the second example, you are missing the word `versions` before `--json`

Answer (score 6):

This `npm-check-updates` package will help you to update and check the latest available package.

- `$ ncu`  Checking package.json
- `$ ncu -u`  Update all packages.
- `$ ncu -g` Check global packages.

For more details check this link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: saves lot of time and effort! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is also another easy way to check the latest version without going to NPM if you are using VS Code.

> In package.json file check for the module you want to know the latest
>   version. Remove the current version already present there and do CTRL
>   + space or CMD + space(mac).The VS code will show the latest versions

[image: image shows the latest versions of modules in vscode]

Comment: This does not work currently with the latest version of vscode.

Comment: @AchyutRastogi I am not sure why its not working for you. Its working fine in my VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I just want to see the commithub current version and I find the way! Let's take a look together

```bash
npm list commithub version -g
```

This gives this output

```bash
/Users/hasan.tezcan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib
└── commithub@0.0.1
```

But I just want to see the version in output

```bash
npm list --depth=0 commithub -g | awk '/commithub@/{gsub(/.*@/, "", $NF); print $NF}'
```

After that I can able to see only version that is amazing

```
0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm view express versions --json | grep -E '^ *"'\
  | sort -rV | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/^ *"(.+)",*$/\1/'
```

(currently `5.0.0-beta.1`)

With major version specified:

```bash
npm view express versions --json | grep -E '^ *"4\.'\
  | sort -rV | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/^ *"(.+)",*$/\1/'
```

(currently `4.18.2`)

With both major & minor specified:

```bash
npm view express versions --json | grep -E '^ *"3\.16\.'\
  | sort -rV | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/^ *"(.+)",*$/\1/'
```

(currently `3.16.10`)

If you want to play around with these commands, you can start by dumping the JSON array of versions into a file:
`npm view express versions --json > express_versions.json`.

Next, `cat express_versions.json | grep -E '^ *"4\.'` to see only the lines starting with zero or more spaces, followed by the string `"4.`

Next, `cat express_versions.json | grep -E '^ *"3\.16\.' | sort -rV` to see `3.16.x` versions `r`everse-sorted using [version sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version-sort-implementation.html).

Tack  `| head -n 1` onto that to show only the first line, in this case   `"3.16.10",`.

Finally,  `| sed -E 's/^ *"(.+)",*$/\1/'` strips   `"3.16.10",` down to `3.16.10`.

docs:
[`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-view)
[`grep --extended-regexp` (`-E`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dG)
[`sort --reverse` (`-r`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-_002dr-3)
[`sort --version-sort` (`-V`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-_002dV)
[`head --lines` (`-n`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html#index-_002dn-3)
[`sed --extended-regexp` (`-E`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm view @azure/static-web-apps-cli dist-tags.latest
```

Returns 1.1.6