# npm `wanted` vs `latest`

Tags: node.js, npm

I use `npm` to install some command line tools. Having the itch to always be up to date, I found the command `npm -g outdated`.

What is the difference between the columns `wanted` and `latest`?

The documentation states:

> The resulting field 'wanted' shows the latest version according to the
>   version specified in the package.json, the field 'latest' the very
>   latest version of the package.

However I don't find it clear at all.
For example on my system I get:

```
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
cordova    5.3.1   5.3.3   5.3.1  lib
npm        3.3.4   3.3.4   3.3.3  lib
```

How can `wanted` be higher than `latest`? It seems to contradict:

> the field 'latest' the very latest version of the package

Which version should I update to (I only use the command-line, not any node.js code)?

Comment: What version of npm do you use? This doesn't make any sense at all. Those wanted versions doesn't even exists according to npmjs.com

Comment: `npm --version` says `3.3.4`, which matches what `npm -g outdated` shows.

Comment: The ```outdated``` command use npmjs.com to grad the version numbers and the website state that 3.3.3 is indeed the "latest" https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm. Which would explain the divergence of numbers. However, how you ended up with the 3.3.4 is a mystery. Maybe it took a beta or something?

Comment: Where did it take the `wanted` value? To be honest, initially I did `npm -g update`. Then when I saw that `npm` was still in the outdated list, I did `npm -g update npm`. Not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: I'm using n to manage node versions an it's outputting inconsistently too.

Comment: The `latest` is not the real latest, it is a dist-tag. The npm package use 'next' for the latest version and latest for the older one.

Comment: It seems the [NPM documentation on the `outdated` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) has been updated and now describes the differences clearly:

Comment: I have the opposite problem: `wanted` is lesser than `latest`, but I still can't install the latest version!

Answer (score 27):

The `wanted` field makes no sense in the context of a --global run as there is no `package.json` to define which version you require.

> Which version should I update to (I only use the command-line, not any node.js code)?

The latest version seems as a good choice if you like to live on the edge.

The wanted column seems like a bug, it is reported in github [many](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9790) [times](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9690).

### Update (after checking source)

The documentations seems a bit misleading so lets clarify:

> The resulting field 'wanted' shows the latest version according to the version specified in the package.json...

As there is no global package.json, the version constrain used is '*' (set [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/72a692676c364f12312e6e5461f395c3d61070a4/lib/outdated.js#L301)).

Then the wanted version is the latest version of the package according to [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver).

> the field 'latest' the very latest version of the package.

Thats not true, what you get is the [dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) "latest", that usually matches the latest version (see [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/72a692676c364f12312e6e5461f395c3d61070a4/lib/outdated.js#L377)). There are some packages that uses those tags to manage what get shown (like npm).

> Which version should I update to (I only use the command-line, not any node.js code)?

It seems that the edge is **wanted**.

Comment: Great answer!  One correction:  Rather than `*`, global packages which were manually installed will have `dep.package._requested.spec` (`_requested.spec` added to the module `package.json` file) which is the version specification requested for installation.  So after `npm install -g eslint@4.0.0` the wanted version will be 4.0.0 rather than latest.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

On my machine currently `npm -g outdated` shows:

```
Package         Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
babel-cli        6.1.18   6.2.0   6.2.0
generator-rise    1.7.0   2.1.0   2.1.0
npm               3.3.6   3.5.0   3.4.1
```

The version `3.5.0` exists as a release on github but has not yet been published to npm. So it is somehow getting picked up from there but glossing over the npm source I couldn't find any evidence to support this argument.

---

From the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated):

> The resulting field 'wanted' shows the latest version according to the
>   version specified in the package.json, the field 'latest' the very
>   latest version of the package.

To elaborate:

`npm` allows you to specify a range of versions in your package.json, examples are available [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver). The maximum version that can be accommodated in the specified range is the `wanted` column.

This may be different from the version installed (if at all) because package.json may have changed in the meanwhile, or the author may have pushed a new minor release in between.

Comment: But there is no `package.json` as it is running with --global

Comment: npm@3.5.0 is released in npm, but it is not dist-tagged as latest, so it doesn't get shown on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example, cordova@5.3.3 is marked as “wanted”, but “latest” is cordova@5.3.1 because npm uses dist-tags to manage its latest and next release channels.

`npm update` will install the newest version, but `npm install cordova` (with no semver range) will install whatever’s tagged as latest.

[link to documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/outdated.html)