# How do I upgrade my npm installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been unable to upgrade my `npm` installation.

I tried installing a new version of `npm`:

1.Step

```
npm install npm -g

npm install npm --save-dev
```

---

2.Step

```
npm outdated 

Package  Current  Wanted  Latest
npm        3.5.3   3.5.4   3.5.3
```

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tiko",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

---

```
npm update

npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\npm\node_modules\init-pa
ckage-json with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-ins
tall-checks with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gy
p with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog
with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-pa
ckage-json with new installed version
```

---

```
npm outdated 

Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
npm        3.5.4   3.5.4   3.5.3  tiko
```

Is the `npm` update not working?

Comment: The latest version is `3.5.3`. This means you cannot upgrade to a newer version yet.

Comment: @gnerkus Why "Wanted = 3.5.4" ?

Comment: It is the 'edge' version. It's not stable but it's available. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689865/npm-wanted-vs-latest

Comment: @gnerkus -I trying installeg local.  Why global should be  ? -  WARN prefer global npm@3.5.3 should be installed with -g

Comment: Local packages are restricted to a project; global packages can be used within any project. `npm` is a package which is also a package manager so it needs to be available globally.

Comment: @gnerkus Thank You) You my hero )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your `npm` installation using `npm` itself.

You need to install the newest version of `npm` as a global package:

```
$ npm install npm -g
```

Comment: I trying, but not updating. npm        3.5.3   3.5.4   3.5.3

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file?

Comment: gnerkus, yes. Need You see?

Comment: Can you add it to your question?

Comment: it is do not need? -   npm install npm --save-dev

Comment: Sometimes, the `npm update` command does not update the `npm` version. I've edited the answer.