# How to deal with deprecation warnings from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Nearly all the time I use `npm` to install a package, I get a warning like:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

Then I install the dubious packages with the advised version number.

Is there any way to make `npm` do this automatically? At own risk of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM warn message about deprecated package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236735/npm-warn-message-about-deprecated-package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not depending directly on the deprecated packages, you're probably not accomplishing anything by installing them directly. Whichever package depends on it is the one that needs to update its dependencies, and so on until you reach the package you're developing. Essentially: if it's important (e.g. a security problem), notify the package maintainers; if not, ignore the deprecation warning.

Comment: How do I identify which package generated the warning?

Comment: @Polyergic: Run `npm ls <deprecated-package>` and look at the parent(s) of the deprecated package in the resulting tree.