# What are the Warnings, I am getting on installing node packages?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting the following Error while installing Node Package. npm install gives up to date.

[image]

Comment: These are some npm warnings. Not errors

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara Yes these errors how to solve them

Answer (score 0):

These are some npm warnings. Not errors. [See how node package deprication works](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/how_node_package_deprecation_works/).

Comment: That is answered before. Just take a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889519/how-to-deal-with-deprecation-warnings-from-npm)