# React native issues

Tags: react-native

I'm a mobile app beginner developer and I started with react-native.
I had created my first app with npx react-native init command and while the creating began; I received the following warnings:

npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0

The app was probably created but I want to know If I still work, keeping those warns; it won't disturb me.
If yes, what should I do to resolve those issues?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: These warnings are just deprecation notices which would not stop your app from working. React and React Native depends on many modules, which are also depends on others. Fixing these warnings would be hard because you need to update or change those dependencies. If you want to know why one of these packages installed you can use `npm ls` or `npm la` command. `npm ls source-map-url`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889519/how-to-deal-with-deprecation-warnings-from-npm

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time some of your dependencies will be deprecated.

Deprecated means that the package is unmaintained and will no longer be updated by the publisher.

However, this doesn't mean that it won't work. Some packages like ['moment'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) are deprecated and still get millions of downloads every week.

Although, if you can choose between a deprecated package and an active one, always chose the undeprecated one.

Remember that your dependencies also have dependencies, so it's very likely that you won't be able to decide and will have to use deprecated dependencies.

Please, in the future try to be more descriptive with the title of the question and use the format for code and terminal logs. This will help you get better answers.