# Find packages that give deprecated warning- NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, deprecated, npm-install

I have lot of dependencies installed. while `npm install` I am getting `npm warn` deprecated please update to some version. how to find which package produces this warning.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341065/1740715

Comment: that will suggestions for all @Harikrishnan. I want to see that in particular.

Answer (score 20):

`npm outdated` only shows packages that have newer versions available, independent of their deprecation status. Thus, it does not show deprecated packages that won't get updates anymore (e.g. `request` or `@hapi/joi`).

If you use `npm` version 7 or newer, you should have a *package-lock.json* with `lockfileVersion: 2`. This lockfile contains the deprecation warnings of all installed packages.

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to find all packages that have deprecation warnings:

```sh
jq -r '.packages | to_entries[] | select(.value.deprecated != null) | "\(.key):\n\(.value.deprecated)\n"' package-lock.json
```

The output will look like this:

```
node_modules/har-validator:
this library is no longer supported

node_modules/request:
request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

node_modules/request-oauth/node_modules/uuid:
Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

node_modules/request/node_modules/uuid:
Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

Comment: If this returns transitive dependencies that aren't declared in your package.json, `npm explain <dependency>` will show the declared dependencies are bringing them in.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package can do this.

```
npm install -g npm-deprecated-check
ndc
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and run these two commands:

1. `cd`
2. `npm outdated`

It should return a list of outdated packages that need to be upgraded.

Comment: Deprecated notices come from sub-dependencies. `npm outdated` does not consider sub-dependencies. Updating direct dependencies might fix the issue, or it might not.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: `npm i` gives you warns about a deprecated sub-dependency.

Fix: `npm list --depth=3 >> result.txt` then you can search in that file for the deprecated sub package