# Can I automatically clean deprecated @types/ packages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, package.json

I'm upgrading an old typescript project. Many years ago, most packages had corresponding `@types` packages. Nowadays, typings are usually included in the main package, therefore typing packages got obsolete.

A typical example is [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup). Many years ago it needed [@types/yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yup), but now it's deprecated.

I have 30+ typing packages in my project, and because I don't want to manually clean them, I'm asking:

1. What if I just leave them in `pakages.json`? I guess there is a big chance they would mislead typescript and IDE, right?
2. Is there a command or script to list or clean deprecated packages?

Comment: Mmm, maybe `npm outdated` or `npm-check`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236735/npm-warn-message-about-deprecated-package

Comment: `I don't want to manually clean them,`,  You only have 30, it's surely not that hard to manually edit `package.json` to delete them, and run `npm i` to update.  Or am I missing something..?

Comment: If this is something you need to do a lot, one idea is to just create a simple node script,.. First load `package.json`, search all packages for `@types/` then scan the directory for that package, if there are any `.d.ts` files remove from `package.json`, finally `npm i` to update `node_modules`

Comment: @Keith I was expecting someone to solve this common issue already...

Comment: @vera. `npm-outdated` shows packages that have a newer version released, but not deprecated ones. However, deprecated packages can be seen in `npm i` output.

Comment: @Dan   Might be.   But when I was using `pnpm` there were lots of things that I wanted to do inside a mono-repo automatically, and though, oh, somebody would have done this already.  But after searching for ages, decided it was quicker just to make a simple CLI tool that did things I wanted.   In the end I'm glad I did, as it just makes my workflow work the way I want..  Also my previous suggest of searching for `.d.ts` files might not be required, I think the `types` prop of a package.json will tell you if it's got types built in, so that makes it a tad easier.

Comment: Edit: actually forget about the bit about looking for `types` in package.json, just looked at yup, and it just places the `.d.ts` files in the same directory as `.js` files, there is no `types` prop, or anything in package.json to say it's got types, so a search for `.d.ts` files seems the most reliable way to know if a package has built in types.. :(