# Installing passport strategy for node application results in npm warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, passport.js

I want to use the passport magic link for my project but get two depreciation warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

When I checked the referenced packages in npm I don't see alternatives and the two packages in question look like they have a circular dependency.

I'm not sure what to do here as this is my first choice. I don't really know of any other auth packages other than paid with Auth0 or AWS Cognito etc. Suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you tried to search for an answer before post? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236735/npm-warn-message-about-deprecated-package) is a good place to start.