# How to find the latest stable version of an npm package?

Tags: npm

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/nodejs-npm-show-latest-version-of-a-module) covers how to get the npm CLI to show the latest version of a package:

```
npm view [PKG_NAME] version
```

But if I do `npm view async version` I get `2.0.0-rc.6`, which is a release candidate.

Is there a command that will tell me the current **stable** version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list only the stable versions not the beta then

```
npm view bootstrap@* version
```

to install the latest stable version

```
npm install bootstrap@*
```

Comment: To install the latest stable, isn't it just `npm install bootstrap`?

Comment: No, it will give you latest, but not stable. For example knockout it gives you "3.5.0-beta".

Comment: I run `npm view bootstrap@* version` on my shell but get a 'no matches found: bootstrap@*', what may be the problem?

Comment: try `npm view [PKG_NAME] version`