# Show most recently published versions of npm package, including beta versions

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

How can I show the most recently published versions of an npm package, including beta/unstable versions?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/nodejs-npm-show-latest-version-of-a-module) helps identify how you can get the most recent, stable version (does not show beta version), but I would like to see a list of the several most recent versions, *including* beta versions.

```
$ npm view webpack versions

  ...
  '0.7.9',
  '0.7.11',
  '0.7.12',
  '0.7.13',
  '0.7.14',
  '0.7.15',
  '0.7.16',
  '0.7.17',
  '0.8.0-beta1',
  '0.8.0-beta2',
  ... 316 more items ]
```

I would like to show the "tail" of this list, instead of seeing the first several packages that were released. Is this possible?

*How can I show a list of the most recently released versions for a particular npm package?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs npm show latest version of a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/nodejs-npm-show-latest-version-of-a-module)

Comment: `npm view web pack versions | tail --lines n ` will show the last _n_ versions

Comment: @Chad I'd like to show the latest several modules, and I'd like them to include beta versions, not just the latest stable release.

Comment: @mparnisari, I got an error with your suggestion "tail: illegal option -- -"

Comment: @Himmel Then just tail it:  npm view webpack versions | tail -n 10

Comment: @Chad `... | tail -n 10` still shows "...316 more items"

Comment: @Himmel Then npm must be pre-parsing the json and rendering it. Write a script to parse the json from the registry link.

Comment: @Chad How do I find the registry link for a particular package?

Comment: @Himmel https://registry.npmjs.org/<package>, so for example: https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack

Answer (score 29):

You can use `--json` flag to output all the versions in the json format, which is quite human-readable

Answer (score 9):

I could not overcome that *...xxx more items]* issue until I found [this blog post](http://willi.am/blog/2015/07/17/viewing-all-versions-of-an-npm-package-including-pre-release/) by Will Anderson, who should get credits:

> npm view some-package-name**@*** version

The trick is to have a glob with all available package versions, and then for each one of those show its "latest" (one and only) version.

**EDIT**

As per comment observation (and original blog post), that does **not** show pre-release versions. To also get pre-release versions and not incur into `... XX more items ]` output, one can run (note plural `versions`):

> npm view some-package-name versions --json

Comment: Great suggestion, but it seems like this still does not show all versions, for example `react@16.0.0-alpha.12` is a version not shown.