# Relationship between the version of node.js and the version of @types/node

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm just started using node and wanted to try it with typescript. I did an `npm install @types/node` and the latest version was 7.0.4:

```
$ npm install @types/node
test-simple-node-typescript@0.1.0 /home/wink/prgs/test-simple-node-typescript
└── @types/node@7.0.4
```

Where as the latest version of node is 7.5.0:

```
$ node --version
v7.5.0
```

What is the relationship between the version of node.js and that of @types/node?

Comment: I think types declaration for node has not changed from version 7.0.0. There was just 4 minor updates to typings.

Comment: @misaz, thanks for the info, but how would I know that @types/node version 7.0.4 === node version 7.5.0? Also, when I went to the [DefinitelyTyped issues](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues) I saw [Merge `node` changes from @types org](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14418) which left me feeling that things were out of date or incorrect.

Comment: Typings is for node 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, ... the same. When major version (eg. 7.0.0) is released then no change in API is allowed in minor update. Because this 7.1.0 has the same typings as 7.0.0. version 7.2.0 too. version 7.4.0 too. ... Typings 7.0.0 was released for 7.0.0 then he found some bugs in typings or needs to improve and was forced to release new typings 7.0.1, then 7.0.2, then 7.0.3, then 7.0.4. Node series 7.X.Y has all typings version 7.0.Z. X != Y != Z. Dependency between node and typing version is only in first number.

Comment: If anyone needs it, I imagine a good way to deal with this is to update your package.json file and set "@types/node" to "<7.5.0" (and if you're on another version, replace 7.5.0 with whatever you're using). PS: That was really helpful, thanks @Misaz

Comment: the question can be generalized to any DefinitelyTyped package. see [How can I find what versions of a @types package from DefinitelyTyped work with what versions of the actual package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72305928/11107541)

Answer (score 48):

Simply, the major version and minor version tagged in the [semver](https://semver.org/) string of [`@types/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) is exactly corresponding to the node's version.

If you check the [`index.d.ts` file of `@types/node`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v16/index.d.ts) in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository, you'll see what type of node is this declaration file for through the first line comment at the top of the file:

```
// Type definitions for non-npm package Node.js 16.11
// Project: https://nodejs.org/
....
```

Comment: This looks true for newer versions, but old versions seem to have a different numbering system.  Version 7 of @types/node, for example, goes from 7.0.0 through 7.0.71 (as of the time I wrote this comment), and then jumps to 7.10.0.  So it looks like the 7.0.x series correlates to the node versions 7.0 through 7.9.

Comment: For Node 14: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v14/index.d.ts

Comment: For Node 16: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v16/index.d.ts

Comment: I think this **never** holds true, e.g. for NodeJS version 16.17.1, there is no `@types/node@16.17.*`...

Comment: Yes, for lts 18.18.0 there is no corresponding @types/node

Comment: @coler-j, try `npm view @types/node versions --json | grep '"18.18.' | sort -rV | head -n 1` (returns `18.18.9` at the moment)

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich, huh, yeah, looks like it jumped from `16.11` to `16.18`, maybe there were no type changes in the missing minor releases.

Comment: More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/npm-how-to-show-the-latest-version-of-a-package#77491043

Comment: In https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v16/index.d.ts I'm no longer able to see Node.js version mentioned. Am I missing anything here?