# How can I find what versions of a @types package from DefinitelyTyped work with what versions of the actual package?

Tags: types, react-router, react-router-dom

The application I'm working on at work has `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom` to support types for the `react-router` and `react-router-dom` api.
I'm now trying to upgrade the router to 6 and I understand the types version has to be updated accordingly.
Is there a way to find what `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom` work with what versions of `react-router` & `react-router-dom` packages?

Comment: Do you mean something *other than* [source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router-dom)? Also, unless I'm mistaken, `react-router@6` exports its own types, so there may not be a need for any external type definitions. FWIW the `@types/react-router@latest` appears to be the v5 APIs, so this seems to agree with not needing anything extra if upgrading to RRDv6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to relate a version of @types to the versions of the associated package in NodeJS Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071705/how-to-relate-a-version-of-types-to-the-versions-of-the-associated-package-in-n)

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling to find as well. In `node_modules/@types/react-router/index.d.ts` there is a comment like

```
// Type definitions for react-router 3.0
```

Comment: nice. I just posted [an answer that explains why this line exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76221515/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

In general what you see in the DefinitelyTyped project's documentation ["How do Definitely Typed package versions relate to versions of the corresponding library?"](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library) should apply. Authors of the type declaration file will (must) put a line at the very top of the type declaration file like `// Type definitions for Node.js <major version of the library that these types correspond to>.<major version of the library that these types correspond to>`. Ex. `// Type definitions for Node.js 10.12`. The release tooling in the project will automatically bump the patch number for release (the patch number of the types package is unrelated to the patch number of the actual package).

So what you can do is look for that first line in the type declaration file of the types package. If you don't know where to look for that file, look in the package.json file and see the `"types"` property, where the value will point to the type declaration file path (see also [the TypeScript docs for publishing types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)).

What you want to do ideally is match the major and patch number, which I'm pretty sure you can do with a [dependency version constraint](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies) using a leading `~` and matching major and minor version numbers.

Note that as stated in the DefinitelyTyped project docs, sometimes the minor versions of the types package may lag behind the actual package because the people maintaining the types package are mostly separate from the people maintaining the actual package.