# How can i use certain version of node.js in vs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to use an older version of node.js for my project in vs code but since the latest node version is installed i cant use the older version. Even nvm use  doesn't seems to help

I tried using bard to help me with my problem, and it suggested me with using node version manager.
Even though it showed that it is useing that version in terminal, it was not reflecting in the vs code.
i also checked that there is no way to make sure that the node.js version for whole vs code changes unless new path of older version is added in environment variables and latest version is removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between the version of node.js and the version of @types/node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035263/relationship-between-the-version-of-node-js-and-the-version-of-types-node)

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found to be working is to add path of node of the version you want, and move it above the latest version. This will although change the node.js version for your whole system but it is the only way in which you can have both latest and prev version nodejs at same time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zw3e.png)

as you can see the version 18.9.0 is above the nodejs version 20.10.0(latest version).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).