# How to get latest version of my package from npmjs

Tags: npm, npm-publish

For example below is package which is hosted in `npmjs`,

> package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-base

i want to get this package latest version through command with out installing it. is ther anyway available to achieve my requirement

**purpose** - To avoid when i  set version for to publish this package again in npmjs. if i set lower version mistaken

Comment: It somewhat depends on how you define the term _"latest"_. Running `npm show <pkg_name> dist-tags.latest` will return the version tagged as `latest`, and is analogous to `npm show <pkg_name> version`. However, a _"later"_ pkg version may have been published. For instance; prerelease version(s) of a pkg may have been published since the one currently tagged `latest`. To illustrate my point run; `npm show eslint version && npm show eslint versions` - as you can see currently the `latest`  tagged version is `6.8.0`, yet versions `7.0.0-alpha.0`, and `7.0.0-alpha.1` have been published since.

Comment: Tip: If you utilize the [npm-version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) command you'll negate the possibility setting a lower version by mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - how to show the latest version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/npm-how-to-show-the-latest-version-of-a-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
npm show {package name} version
```

It would just fetch the latest version and show, not installing the package.

Also  `npm view` , `npm show` , `npm info` and `npm v` all do the same thing.

Comment: A more accurate description is: _"It would just fetch the `latest` **tagged** version and show, not installing the package."_ or  _"It would just fetch the latest **stable** version and show, not installing the package."_

Comment: Well said. Thats more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the oudated packages via

```
npm outdated
yarn outdated // < yarn equivalent
```

and them simply pipe the specific package you're looking for via any unix search tool

```
npm outdated | grep @syncfusion/ej2-base
```

---

Advantage of this being, it also shows the `current`, `wanted` and `latest` with useful color separation for compatibility. (

[image]

> *Note: Obviously, if your package is up-to-date it won't show here*

Comment: @kumaresan_sd it is, the example picture in my answer is literally from `npm outdated` lol.  **So either your package is up-to-date or you're calling it in incorrect directory**. But I mean, if your package is up to date, you already know its version because it's installed

Comment: is there any way to get outdated version

Comment: What do you mean? Install the outdated version or?

Comment: i want know the outdated version of my package

Comment: I mean if it's not here then it's obviously not outdated at least according to verions @ npm. If you just want to see all the possible versions then do the `npm show` as other answer suggests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208251/discussion-between-kumaresan-sd-and-rawrplus).